# Which 3 hour time interval does time stamp belong to

Tags: r, posixct

I want to determine to which 3-hour interval does time stamp belong to.
First interval ranges from `00:00:01` to `03:00:00`, second from `03:00:01` to `6:00:00` ... Input is in format `POSIXct`.
For example:

input: `time<-Sys.time() #"2019-08-23 03:27:20 CEST"`
output: `2`

(Preferably fastest ways to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cut` by defining `breaks` in a sequence of 3 hours and then convert it into integer.

```
as.integer(cut(time, breaks = seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%T"), 
                as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format = "%T"), by = "3 hours")))
```

and same with `findInterval`

```
findInterval(time, seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%T"), 
                       as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format = "%T"), by = "3 hours"))
```

---

For the updated data shared, we can do

```
x <-structure(-62167133512, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

as.integer(cut(as.POSIXct(format(x, "%T"), format = "%T"), 
breaks = seq(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), "00:00:00")),
             as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date() + 1, "00:00:00")), by = "3 hours")))
#[1] 8
```

Comment: Can you please help me determine why it works for Sys.time() and doesn't for "0-01-01 23:48:08 UTC"?

Comment: @BanAnanas because `"0-01-01 23:48:08 UTC"` is not a valid `POSIXct` value. Check it's `class`. Also check `class(Sys.time())`. You need to convert it into `POSIXct` before using the above.

Comment: I have that value under variable `time`, both `class(time)` and `class(Sys.time())` return `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`.  `as.integer(cut(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%T"), breaks = seq(as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%T"), 
                as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format = "%T"), by = "3 hours")))` returns `NA`

Comment: @BanAnanas No need to use `as.POSIXct` if your `time` is already of class `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`. Do you have many values in `time` ? Can you try `as.integer(cut(time, breaks = "3 hours")) %% 8` If it doesn't work can you show what is `dput(time)` ?

Comment: I added it just in case, no difference if I avoid it. Just this one. `structure(-62167133512, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")`.

Comment: The suggested `as.integer(cut(time, breaks = "3 hours")) %% 8` gives output `1`

Comment: I guess it doesn't understand which is this date `0000-01-01` and hence it is returning `NA`.

Comment: Updated the answer.